# How to disable artifact zipping in upload-artifact@v4?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have this simple workflow:

```yaml
name: Build kategorie pdf
on: [push]
jobs:
  build_latex:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Update + install PDFlatex and fonts
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y texlive-fonts-recommended
          sudo apt-get install -y texlive-fonts-extra
          sudo apt-get install -y texlive-latex-base
          sudo apt-get install -y texlive-latex-extra
      - name: Install pandoc
        uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v2
        with:
          pandoc-version: "3.1.11"
      - name: Pandoc version check
        run: pandoc --version
      - name: Set up Git repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Download statement.lua
        run: |
          git clone https://github.com/dialoa/statement ~/statement
      - name: Compile Markdown to PDF
        run: |
          pandoc -L ~/statement/statement.lua -s kategorie.md -o kategorie.pdf
      - name: Upload PDF artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: kategorie.pdf
          path: kategorie.pdf
```

This builds PDF correctly and uploads it as artifact. But the PDF itself is in ZIP file. How can I disable creating archive with the PDF and just let people download PDF directly?

Comment: As a build artifact you can't, but you _could_ upload it as a file to a release.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible [with `actions/upload-artifact`](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact?tab=readme-ov-file#zip-archives).

> Zip archives
>
> When an Artifact is uploaded, all the files are assembled into an
> immutable Zip archive. There is currently no way to download artifacts
> in a format other than a Zip or to download individual artifact
> contents.

See also: [Uploading a single file](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/3#issue-479904691)

Comment: Is there any other way to make PDF accessible directly ?